# Monitor files with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: powershell, events, monitor

I'm trying to create a PowerShell program to monitor when a file in a certain path is modified, and only if it now contains the string "loaded successfully", to `Write-Host`. Eventually an email component will be added if the string is not found in a certain amount of time.

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\afila\Desktop\TEST' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder
$filter = '*.txt'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

# Function to search folder contents for a string
function Search-Folder {
    $SearchTerm = "Loaded successfully"

    foreach ( $file in $files) {
        $text = Get-Content "$folder\$file"
        if ($text | where {$text -like "*$SearchTerm*" }) {
            Write-Host "The file '$file succeeded" -fore white
            Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\afila\Desktop\SucceededLog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$file' completed at $timeStamp"
        }
    }
}

# Here, all the Changed event is registerd. 
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated  
    $searchTerm = "Loaded successfully"
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $text = Get-Content "$folder\$file"
        if ($text | where {$text -like "*$searchTerm*"}) {
                Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore magenta 
                Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\afila\Desktop\TestLogItems\TestLog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
        }
    }
}

# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands: 
Unregister-Event FileChanged
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystemWatcher` already gives you the full path to the file via the property `$Event.SourceEventArgs.Path`, so you don't need to loop over a list of files.

```
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Path
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    $searchTerm = 'Loaded successfully'

    if ((Get-Content $path) -like "*$searchTerm*"}) {
        Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    }
}
```